# Menu in Refiney CMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, menu, refinerycms

Sorry for that, but a new I new in rails. Well I created an application and I'm started editing the front end pages

In Refinery guide tells me to edit the application.html.erb. Then I started editing as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>A3 Soccer</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
<body>


<div id="page_container">
      <header>
        <h1 id='logo'>
  <a href="http://localhost:3000/"><img src="images/logo.png" /></a>
</h1>
<nav id='menu' class='menu clearfix'>
  <ul>
    <li class='selected first' id='item_0'>
  <a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class='last' id='item_1'>
  <a href="/about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

      </header>
      <section id='page'>
        <section id='body_content' class='no_body_content_right'>


<%= yield %>

 <div id="footer">
     <p>dsfdsfdsf</p>
      </div>



</body>
</html>
```

But this part of the menu is static:

```
<nav id='menu' class='menu clearfix'>
  <ul>
    <li class='selected first' id='item_0'>
  <a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class='last' id='item_1'>
  <a href="/about">About</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

How do I leave it dynamic?

I want to: when I create a page in the admin, that link(of page) to appear in menu of pages on my site

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it is not already dynamic? Create another page and see if it shows up in the navigation. I have not used Refinery in about 6 months but the navigation was always dynamic by default.

Comment: Yes, by default the navegation is dynamic. But when I edited the application.html.erb to put other things inside the site the menu is no longer dynamic.  I believe I need to put some command on application.html.erb to pull information from the admin.

Answer (score 0):

In refinery you typically do not want to override the **application.html.erb** as it generally takes care of all the functionally you need.

You can take a look at what the file is doing here:
https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/core/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb#L1

This file has a lot of calls to other partials that bring in what is needed in each area.  For example the header is with a partial called _header.html.erb seen here:

https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/core/app/views/refinery/_header.html.erb#L1

Again here another partial is called to render the menu - that is dynamic.

I would highly suggest to not override these files as these typically do everything you need by default, but on the chance you do need to override them you can run the command:

bundle exec rake refinery:override view=refinery/_header

(you can run simply rake refinery:override to see examples and other options of how this feature works)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
<%= render(:partial => "/refinery/menu", :locals => {
         :dom_id => 'menu',
         :css => 'menu'
       }) %>
```

to your file.

https://github.com/resolve/refinerycms/blob/master/core/app/views/refinery/_header.html.erb